Chromium browser is broken
I recently had a system freeze during a conversation on Cliq and had to reboot. After rebooting I have seen Chromium no longer works. Tried running it in terminal:
chromium-browser
Gtk-Message: 22:25:38.263: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:25:38.264: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
libpxbackend-1.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/arpad/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222538.583303:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
xdg-desktop-menu
[12803:12803:0704/222538.708344:ERROR:account_info_fetcher.cc(62)] OnGetTokenFailure: Request canceled.
[0704/222538.736499:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222539.123342:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
[12803:12803:0704/222539.171816:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[12803:12911:0704/222539.272366:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1051)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for hu.mohamedopedia.org failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=ls-account) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[12952:12976:0704/222539.277490:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222539.384525:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222539.562891:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222539.816044:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222539.944612:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222540.045360:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222540.251443:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222540.389085:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222540.491262:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222540.701166:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222540.847056:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222540.961886:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222541.162259:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222541.287820:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222541.390697:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222541.612868:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222541.733027:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222541.833175:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222542.022467:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222542.141373:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222542.242725:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222542.439645:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[0704/222542.564318:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222542.663895:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[12803:12803:0704/222542.850927:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
[12803:12803:0704/222542.850950:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(449)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
[0704/222542.856072:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/222542.978474:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0704/222543.015073:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

I have checked for the so files in the cache and found some symlinks (sharing screenshot for the colors and as text too):

ls -l /home/arpad/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arpad arpad 112 Jul  4 21:49 giomodule.cache
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arpad arpad  91 Jul  4 21:49 libdconfsettings.so -> /snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arpad arpad  91 Jul  4 21:49 libgiognomeproxy.so -> /snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arpad arpad  87 Jul  4 21:49 libgiognutls.so -> /snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arpad arpad  89 Jul  4 21:49 libgiolibproxy.so -> /snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so

And when checking for the files they are linking to, they were not found. Even
/snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform

is empty, so the modules folder of
/snap/chromium/2905/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules

where the so files are supposed to be does not even exist. How can I fix my broken Chromium under Ubuntu?

Tried uninstalling it? and then install?

@amar surely. I have uninstalled and reinstalled. I have also tried to manually copy those files from other sources to the place where they are expected, but due to it being a readonly disk, it failed.

What is your version of Ubuntu? and I guess it is Desktop?

@amar it's Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and indeed, it's desktop

There is a couple of bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970611 and this and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chromium-cannot-update-snap-namespace-cannot-expand-mount-entry-none-home-local-share-none-x-snapd-kind-ensure-dir-x-snapd-must-exist-dir-home-0-0-cannot-use-invalid-home-directory/39764

You can also uninstall it and check if there are any leftove rfiles in /home/snap or anywhere else in your system. If it doesn't work guess 2 options available, 1- rename your chromium profile see if it works then, 2 - get an earlier version.

it's most likely not connected with a host OS, that's rather a chromium snap that build with core24(Ubuntu24.04) and gnome extension, which looks like not mounted properly by snap infra. Reversing to last chromium with core22 version (or using .deb version if that exists) could fix it.

@yvs2014 indeed snap refresh to an earlier version fixed the problem, as suggested in the accepted answer.

Had the same issue today, revision 2905 is broken in Ubuntu 22.04.
Do the following:
snap refresh --revision=2897 chromium
That'll install the latest working revision.

Thanks, Rohnlex! It worked like a charm.
